# Trying to populate <h1> text with Javascript For In loop

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the  to populate with companyName from an array. I am not seeing any changes.

Javascript:

```
var webName = {
coinstar: {
    companyName: "Coinstar",
    projectName: "Online App",
    role: "Web Developer",
    detailText: "This is some text"
    },
google: {
    companyName: "Google",
    projectName: "AdWord Security",
    role: "Web Developer",
    detailText: "This is some text"
    },
amazon: {
    companyName: "Amazon",
    projectName: "Internal Site",
    role: "Web Developer",
    detailText: "This is some text"
    }
}

// The is supposed to grab the company name from the above list. 
var search = function(coName){
for(var prop in coName){
    if(webName[prop].companyName === coName){
        document.getElementById("companyName").innerHTML = companyName;
        }
    }
}

var detailTitle = function(){
search("coinstar");
```

HTML: 
    // Click this div to populate

```
// After div is pressed this heading should say "Coinstar".
    <h1 id="companyName">Company name here</h1>
```

Comment: Is it because `<h1 id="companyName>Company name here</h1>` is missing an ending quote?

Comment: Why are you trying to do `for...in` on the string you pass to `search`? It should be as simple as `webName["coinstar"]` to get the object with the key `coinstar`

Comment: I will try this. I may have over thought this.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I'll ignore the fact that `id="companyName>` is missing an ending quote.

In the function:

```
var search = function(coName) {
   for(var prop in coName) {
```

`coName` is the string `coinstar`:

```
search("coinstar");
```

You're attempting to iterate through each property in a `string`, which is probably not what you want.

Perhaps you meant to iterate through your collection of companies:

```
var search = function(coName) {
   for(var prop in webName) {
```

With that said, there's not really a reason to iterate through the collection to find your company name, when you already key the collection by company name.  `webName[coName]` should get you what you want without the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="companyDiv">
</div>
```

In javascript

```
document.getElementById("companyDiv").innerHTML+="<h1>"+companyName+"</h1>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to do `for...in` on the string you pass to `search`. You should be able to just do this:

```
var search = function(coName){
    if(webName[coName]){
        document.getElementById("companyName").innerHTML = webName[coName].companyName;
    }
}
```

If, however, the idea was that the key in your `webName` object and the term passed to search aren't the same, then you can `for...in` over `webName` and try to match `.companyName` (note, however, that string comparisons are case sensitive)

```
var search = function(coName) {
    for(var prop in webName) {
        if(webName.hasOwnProperty(prop) && webName[prop].companyName && webName[prop].companyName.toLowerCase() === coName.toLowerCase()) {
            document.getElementById("companyName").innerHTML = webName[prop].companyName;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: `prop` is now undefined

Comment: @ColinDeClue: Whoops. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var search = function(coName){
 for(var prop in webName){
    if(webName[prop].companyName === coName){
    document.getElementById("companyName").innerHTML = webName[prop].companyName;
    }
 }
}
```